# How to get difference each record value from previous record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

Please consider this Table:

```
Year     Month    Code     Value
--------------------------------
2011      1         1       100
2011      2         1       200
2011      3         1       250
2011      1         2       70
2011      2         2       50
2011      3         2       80
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
Code    FromYearMonth      ToYearMonth    Difference
----------------------------------------------------
 1       2011-1               2011-2        100   <----200 - 100
 1       2011-2               2011-3        50    <----250 - 200
 2       2011-1               2011-2        -20   <----50 - 70
 2       2011-2               2011-3        30    <----80 - 50
```

How can I create this result with `LINQ`. Thanks

Comment: You already have it :). But how to do it in LINQ depends on what the class model looks like and what EF version this is about. Also, why LINQ? This is much easier in SQL. (Sql Server window functions or equivalents).

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks sir. I was wondering if you could write that query in `SQL Version` ? That will help me and other people to increase our knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join datasource with itself to get all pairs of (monthStart, monthEnd) records, then calculate difference:

```
from monthStart in dataSource
join monthEnd in dataSource
on new { monthStart.Code, date = monthStart.Year * 12 + monthStart.Month }
equals new { monthEnd.Code, date = monthEnd.Year * 12 + monthEnd.Month - 1}
select new {
  monthStart.Code,
  FromYear = monthStart.Year,
  FromMonth = monthStart.Month,
  ToYear = monthEnd.Year,
  ToMonth = monthEnd.Month,
  Difference = monthEnd.Value - monthStart.Value
}
```